# Why do ring stains form when leaving glasses on wood?

Tags: everyday-life, water, condensation, glass

From wikipedia:

> Coasters protect the surface of a table or any other surface where the user might place a beverage.

Without coasters, you will often get a ring stain on your table like this:

[image]

What is the science behind these rings forming? I have tried googling but all the results are about removing these rings, and not why they form.

Comment: Probably should be chemistry, not physics, though the condensation of water is physics and cold drinks are good at creating condensation, but the stain is chemistry.

Comment: Also, I don't want to make this an answer, as it's very brief, but here's an explanation under "water is the villain".   http://www.ronhazelton.com/blog/what_causes_those_ugly_white_marks_on_tabletops

Comment: userLTK's comment seems to explain the stain on the right, but the one on the left looks more like mineral deposits from the condensation.

Comment: @userLTK Light diffraction is very physics.

Comment: @peterh  I'm happy to be wrong on this, but I don't see how a semi-permanent stain in the varnish and/or wood isn't chemistry.   The way it interacts with light is, as you say, physics.  What causes the rings to form is chemistry, or,, material science but I don't think there's a board for that.   Anyway, I really am happy to be voted wrong if people see fit.